# Using a filter list with linq to xml

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Is there a way to pass a list of strings to a linq to xml query or do I need to specify each filter separately? I want to count the number of elements that have the same name as the strings in a list.

Here's code that obviously doesn't work but gives you an idea what I'm looking to do:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(pathToXmlFile);

List<string> myList = new List<string> { "node1", "node2" };

int count = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Element(myList)).Count();
```

Obviously, x.Element can't take a list of strings, but is there another way to do this other than typing out individual x.Element("node1"), x.Element("node2"), etc?

**Edit:**

I wasn't able to get it working with implicit conversion to XName, so this is how I did it:

```
int count = doc.Descendants().Where(x => myList.Any(n => x.Name.ToString() == n)).Count();
```

The key to this was the Any method.

Comment: Do you want just a Count() or a List<XElement> ?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve, exactly. Are you trying to find the number of descendants whose names are in that list?

Answer (score 1):

This will work as you expect:

```
int count = doc.Descendants().Where(x => myList.Any(n => x.Element(n))).Count();
```

Comment: That doesn't work because Element() only takes XElements, not strings.

Comment: @u84six: No, that's not true - it takes `XName`, and there's an implicit conversion from `string` to `XName`. Did you try the code first?

Comment: @u84six I was assuming it was only problem with your code. Please provide more details if you need a better answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry, you're right. It takes XName. I will try the conversion.

Comment: @Migol thanks for the reply. It was the list.Any I was looking for anyway. I think I've got it covered. Thanks.